# Analysis Closure and

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am in mathematical analysis and I'm struggling with this homework question and how to get it started:

"Let E be a subset of a metric space X. Prove that x $\in$ $\overline{E}$ if and only if G $\cap$ E $\neq$ $\emptyset$ for every open set G that contains x."

Attempt at proof:

(=>) Let x $\in$ $\overline{E}$. By the definition $\overline{E}$ = E $\cup$ {All the limit points of E}, therefore x $\in$ E. Let G be an open subset of X and x $\in$ G. Then G $\cap$ E $\neq$ $\emptyset$ since x $\in$ G and E.

(<=) Suppose G $\cap$ E $\neq$ $\emptyset$ for every open set G that contains x. Then x is also in E. Since $\overline{E}$ = E $\cup$ {All the limit points of E}, x $\in$ $\overline{E}$.

Comment: Try to run your argument with the set $E=(0, 1]$ and $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $F = X  \setminus \bar E$   is open so $x \in F$ iff there is   a  neighbourhood of $x$ in $F$ which is an open set $U$ containing $x$ and $U \cap \bar E = \varnothing $.